# Facebook SDK error in AppDelegate application function even with updated Facebook in Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, swift, appdelegate

So I updated Xcode and got a bunch of errors which were easy fixes but then, after updating the FBSDK, I got an error in my AppDelegate which I just can't seem to fix:

```
/Users/wylerzahm/Desktop/AppName/AppName/AppDelegate.swift:23:58: Cannot invoke 'application' with an argument list of type '(UIApplication, openURL: NSURL?, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)'
```

The actual function giving the error is as follows:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL?, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

The function is necessary for the Facebook login to work. Any help is appreciated.
The function being invoked is as follows:

```
@interface FBSDKApplicationDelegate : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

Please if anyone can help!

Comment: Post the declaration of the function being invoked.

Comment: I added the code of the invoked function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just encountered this issue as well after upgrading to XCode 6.3 with Swift 1.2.

The issue appears to be that the sourceApplication type was updated from `NSString` to `String` in the function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

So it should be:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Cheers!

Edit: As noted by Ruud Kalis, the annotation type was also updated from `AnyObject` to `AnyObject?`

Comment: Thanks dude! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Perfect bud thanks, you saved me some messing about.

Answer (score 1):

Note also the change from `AnyObject` to `AnyObject?`. If this is not changed the compiler will still complain.